# Reloading SubViews in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, subview

I am developing an iOS application and using a parent page with two subviews as follows:

```
    var v1: assetType1VC = assetType1VC(nibName: "assetType1VC", bundle: nil)
    var v2: cityChart1VC = cityChart1VC(nibName: "cityChart1VC", bundle: nil)



    self.addChild(v1)
    self.addChild(v2)

    self.scrollView.addSubview(v1.view)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(v2.view)


    v1.didMove(toParent: self)
    v2.didMove(toParent: self)

    var v2Frame: CGRect = v2.view.frame
    v2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
    v2.view.frame = v2Frame

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 2 , height: 1)
```

However, my problem is that all the two subviews are loaded at the same time.

What I want to achieve is: I would like to reload v2 when it appears.
I have used viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear but both did not work with me

Answer (score 1):

The easiest but ugly way to reload `UIView` is to use :

```
self.v2.setNeedsLayout()
self.v2.layoutIfNeeded()
```